# How to set _locale dynamically based on host

Tags: symfony

Is there any way to set _locale parameter of routing configuration as a function call or an expression result? I have multiple hosts running on the same symfony app, and there is an i18n turned on. Everything is working fine, but now i need to have another locales set for a specified host.

Right now my routing config looks like

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    ...
    requirements:
        _locale: '%route_locales%'
    ...
```

and i have something like this in parameters:

```
  ...
  route_locales: en|de|fr
  ...
```

That would be perfect if i can use something like

```
   "@=service('AppBundle\\\\...\\\\LocalesConfigurator').getLocales()"
```

as a _locale: value to get this value based on a function call result. Or maybe there are some other options to get another _locale set for a specified host?

Comment: how about setting it via environment variable?

Comment: But all hosts are served by one project(one application, one folder), so they have a same environment. Maybe i've misunderstood your advice.

Comment: nginx can pass data via the `fastcgi_param` directive (which can be set in every different server) and which would be usable via `%env(resolve:...)%` in the services.yaml parameters section. ... well ... at least that's true for symfony >=4.1 I believe ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like @Jakumi suggested (via env params passed from server)

or using only application logic:

1. In **route_locales** put all possible locales that can be used in any host.
2. Validate incoming **_locale** inside "request listener" depending on request host - if some **_locale** is not allowed for host then return 404 response or show 404 error page etc.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i've found at least one solutuin, thanks to Jakumi for the idea. I've created a parameter in my config file, which receives an environment varaible. Then i use this parameter in my routing file. The main idea is that i can control this environment variable value using bootstrap file. So it looks like
bootstrap.php (in the example it's just a static value, but in a real life this value will depend on host).

**bootstrap.php**

```
...
$_SERVER['SYMFONY__ROUTE__LOCALES'] = 'en|es';
...
```

**config.yml**

```
parameters:
    route_locales: '%route.locales%'
```

**routing.yml**

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    ...
    requirements:
        _locale: '%route_locales%'
    ...
```

I don't realy like this solution, and will be thankful for any better solutions, but at least it does what i want.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same issue some months ago and I was able to found a solution that worked correctly, but there may also be some better ones.

As I needed different route names to be loaded depending on the locale (i.e. /contact in English and /contacto in Spanish) what I did was creating the methods in the controller and creating an individual link to them in routes.yaml

```
contact-en:
  path: /contact/
  controller: App\Controller\ContactController::index
  host: domain1.tld

contact-es:
  path: /contacto/
  controller: App\Controller\ContactController::index
  host: domain2.tld
```

Then I created an EventListener called LocaleSwitcher:

```
class LocaleSwitcher
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $host = $request->getHost();

        switch($host) {
            case 'domain1.tld': {
                $request->setLocale('en');
                break;
            }
            case 'domain2.tld': {
                $request->setLocale('es');
                break;
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

And then adding it in services.yaml for event kernel.request and priority 20:

```
App\EventListener\LocaleSwitcher:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, priority: 20 }
```